# ogr2ogr: casting field to string

Tags: sql, csv, ogr, ogr2ogr, typecast

I am attempting a simple data extraction from an Oracle database to a CSV file using ogr2ogr.exe
(the version packaged with QGIS 3.8 i.e. ..QGIS_3.8\bin\ogr2ogr.exe )

I have a field ("Mapsheet") with values like : '092H034','114P055','082E033'

Values with the letter 'E', bracketed with integers (ex. '082E033') are a problem - ogr2ogr extracts these as exponential notation! What I see in my output CSV file is a float, not a string: 8.2e34

I have employed the following SQL as a workaround:

`select (s.mapsheet || '_') as Mapsheet from myTable as s`

That SQL is contained in a separate myFile.sql file, so the call looks something like this:
`ogr2ogr.exe -f "CSV" test.csv OCI:user/password@DBP01 -sql @T:\myFile.sql -overwrite`

I would of course prefer to cast the data using OGR SQL, since my workaround above appends an extra '_' character to the end of the value ... not ideal.

I've tried these CAST statements but they still result in a float number (ex. 8.2e34) being written to my CSV file.

`cast(s.mapsheet AS char(7)) as Mapsheet`

`cast(s.mapsheet AS character(7)) as Mapsheet`

So, how can I properly cast this field to be string values?

Comment: Because the data source is Oracle you are actually not using OGR SQL dialect but native Oracle dialect. Interesting case. Is that field reported as string if you run `ogrinfo OCI:.... -so`?